# How to save the background of a button after closing the app?

Tags: android

I've been working on a social app on android and I have an issue that I couldn't solve. I have a button in every item of my `ListView`.

When the user presses this button, the background changes to another color but when I close the app the color of the button should become the default color.

Comment: I hope you are creating model for the `listview`. You can store them in `SharedPreferences` using `Set`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) for reference.

Comment: What do you mean by a "model for the listview" ?

Comment: Okay... I will post a sample code to explain you better.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it .

Comment: Hi Frank, sorry for late reply. I found using `GSON` is much simpler than `Set`. I have posted the answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: Please add what you tried yourself, so the actual (or existing) code can actually be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a model class for storing the color information of each list item.

**ListModel.java**

```
public class ListModel implements Serializable
{
    String title;
    int color;

    public ListModel(String title, int color) {
        this.title = title;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

In activity, create initialize the `ListView` and assign an adapter to it. Here, when user presses the back button, we will convert the list of color information into `JSON` using `GSON` library and store it into `SharedPreferences`. And when activity is created, get the `JSON` from the `SharedPreferences` and again convert it back into `List` object using `GSON`.

**Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyListAdapter adapter;
    private List<ListModel> dataList;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        if (preferences.contains("Key")) {
            String jsonStr = preferences.getString("Key", "");
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<ListModel>>() {
            }.getType();
            dataList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, type);
        } else {
            dataList = new ArrayList<>();
            fillData();
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, dataList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void changeColor(int position) {
        dataList.get(position).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    }

    private void fillData() {
        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
        dataList.add(new ListModel("Button 1", color));
        dataList.add(new ListModel("Button 2", color));
        dataList.add(new ListModel("Button 3", color));
        dataList.add(new ListModel("Button 4", color));
        dataList.add(new ListModel("Button 5", color));
        dataList.add(new ListModel("Button 6", color));

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        //Set the values
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(dataList);
        editor.putString("Key", json);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

**MyListAdapter.java**

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private final Context context;
    private final List<ListModel> list;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<ListModel> list)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }
    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        Button button;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItemBtn);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        ListModel model = list.get(position);
        holder.button.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.button.setBackgroundColor(model.getColor());
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                ((MainActivity)context).changeColor(position);

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And in `build.gradle`, add `GSON` dependency

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you shouldn't rely on the the buttons themselves, you should have something called *model* behind the scene to store *state* of those buttons. So, you can save that model, which stores state of all buttons, to a persistent memory (e.g. Database, file, Shared Preferences, etc) when your app is closed.